# wxsizer does not work in a child panel,when added after an event (wxwidgets 2.8 , windows xp)

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a top level frame (MyFrame Class) which has a child tree (MyTreeCtrl class)and a child panel (MyPanel class) . An object of MyPanel exists in MyTreeCtrl . An event on a node in the tree should populate the panel.I am setting a sizer with the panel ,but it does not get set.  When the sizer is set to the panel while setting the sizer for its parent frame, everything is fine. But ,when trying to set panel sizer in a separate function, it does not work.

```
void MyTreeCtrl::PopulateElementNode(wxTreeItemId &id)
{

//adding panel control elements and setting its sizer


wxBoxSizer *paneltopsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
(this->mypanel)->SetSizer(paneltopsizer);

this->MyListCtrl=new wxListCtrl(this->mypanel,
    wxID_LISTCTRL,wxDefaultPosition,wxSize(245,100),wxLC_REPORT);
wxButton *Add=new wxButton(this->mypanel,wxID_ADD,wxT("Add"));
wxButton *Delete=new wxButton(this->mypanel,wxID_DELETE,wxT("Delete"));
wxButton *ApplyChanges=new wxButton(this->mypanel,wxID_APPLYCHANGES,wxT("ApplyChanges"));

wxBoxSizer *panelbuttonsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
panelbuttonsizer->Add(Add,0,wxALL|wxALIGN_RIGHT,5);
panelbuttonsizer->Add(Delete,0,wxALL|wxALIGN_RIGHT,5);
panelbuttonsizer->Add(ApplyChanges,0,wxALL|wxALIGN_RIGHT,5);
paneltopsizer->Add(this->MyListCtrl,1,wxALL|wxEXPAND,10);
paneltopsizer->Add(panelbuttonsizer,0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALL, 5);

//panel control ends
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that part of the problem here is that you set the panel sizer before you even filled the sizer with controls.

Additionally, you should really be either calling SetSizerAndFit() instead of SetSizer() (note: this will definitely need to be done **after** the controls have been added to the sizer), or alternatively call `mypanel->Layout()` (note: the panel's layout method, not the sizer) after adding the sizer and controls. The latter approach should work fine with setting the sizer before adding the controls, but still has to happen last. In either case, it's really not even logical to set the panel's sizer before you've adding anything to the sizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(this->mypanel)->SetSizer(paneltopsizer);
```

When you call this, you set the instance of MyTreeCtrl to have the new sizer.  This deletes any previous sizer that may have been assigned to the MytreeCtrl instance ( Are you sure that is what you want? )

It does nothing else, unless the MytreeCtrl instance later on receives a resize message.  But you probably want the sizer to do something, right?  So you have to add some code to make the sizer execute.

One way might be to add

paneltopsizer->Layout() at the end of void MyTreeCtrl::PopulateElementNode()

Something will now happen.  I do not know if it will be what you want!  I do not really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to create a tree based XML editor . The panel is not set with a sizer initially . I intent to keep it plain till an event on a node in the tree. Only when the user selects a node ,the sizer needs to be set and the panel populated with its children.

Comment: With my existing code , only the listctrl appears on the panel at (0,0) . When i give paneltopsizer->Layout() at the end of void MyTreeCtrl::PopulateElementNode()   , just a blink appears on the panel and it remains plain.

Comment: When the user selects a node a panel should be populated with the data for that node - OK, fine.  This panel could be a pop-up or it could be a permanent panel in the application window.  In either case it should NOT be a child of the tree control.  IMHO, trying to make the panel containing details of the selected tree node a child of the tree control will cause you no end of difficulty.

Comment: Sorry,if i confused you.The panel is not the child of the treecontrol.Both treecontrol and panel are children of the top level frame. I just included a panel object in the treecontrol class for communication,which does not interfere with the parentage of both. To troubleshoot the issue, i altered the code by including a non-window class which has both treecontrol and panel instance , instead of including the panel instance inside treecontrol class. I did it because the panel and treecontrol instances are related . Even doing this, did not solve the issue.

Comment: Hey . I found a workaround for the issue. I added both the tree and the panel to a non-window class.I also added the panel's sizer (paneltopsizer) to this class. Then i could set the paneltopsizer to the panel while setting the top level frame's controls.This also allowed me to set the panel's children at a later stage .